# How to connect to docker container by IP from host machine?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am running `Docker For Mac` and I need to set up a test environment including multiple apps and each of them run inside a Docker container. I have a test client tool which is used to test connection through ssh on these containers. But I don't know how to access these containers through its IP addresses.

I know that I can map the port number to a different port on my host but I can't change the test client tool to use a different port number for ssh connection. And that tool can be only run on Mac OS so I can't run this tool from another docker container.

Therefore, I need a way to access these containers through their IP address from my host. I tried to use the IP address from `docker inspect` but it doesn't work. I am free to use any docker related technologies such as compose, swarm but I don't know how to do that.